Pyspark occurrence counts and its distribution
I have a DataFrame[Rand: double, Flag: int, Value: int]. I wanna to do the following with this data.

In col 'Flag', count the total number of occasions where there are more than 3 consecutive 0s.
Distribution of number of occasions as the function of length of consecutive block of 0s.

my code:

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lag, when, sum as _sum
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("ConsecutiveZeros").getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.csv("file.csv", header=True, inferSchema=True)
window = Window.orderBy("Flag")
df = df.withColumn(
    "start_streak", F.col("Flag").cast("int") * F.col("Flag").cast("int") - F.lag("Flag").over(window).cast("int")
)
df = df.withColumn(
    "streak_id", F.sum("start_streak").over(Window.orderBy("Flag"))
)

filtered_df = df.filter(F.col("streak_id") > 3).select("streak_id").distinct()
total_occurrences = filtered_df.count()
print(f"Total occasions with more than 3 consecutive 0s: {total_occurrences}")


But it is giving me in correct results, Can someplace help me here

Please provide the input and the desired output.

The below code will do a cumulative count of consecutive 1s or 0s.  You can later on filter them as per your requirement.
    df = spark.createDataFrame([["x",1],["x",1],["x",0],["x",0],["x",0],\
                                ["x",1]], ["col1", "col2"])
    w0=Window.orderBy(monotonically_increasing_id())
    df=df.withColumn("lag",lag(col("col2")).over(w0))
    df=df.withColumn("flag",when(col("lag")!=col("col2"),1).otherwise(lit(0)))
    df=df.withColumn("row",row_number().over(Window.orderBy(lit("A"))))
    df=df.withColumn("window",sum(col("flag")).over(Window.orderBy(col("row"))))
    df=df.withColumn("cont_count",count(col("col1")).over(Window.partitionBy(col("window")).orderBy(col("row"))))
    df.show()

